# Switching between light and dark themes

Tags: javascript, html, css

Okay so right now I'm storing which theme the user is currently using in `localStorage` and when the page loads I do a check and show either light or dark theme:

```
var currentTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme-mode');

if (currentTheme !== null && currentTheme === 'theme-dark') {
    $('body').addClass('theme-dark');
    $('#btnChangeTheme').html('Dark Theme: On');
} else {
    $('body').removeClass('theme-dark');
    localStorage.removeItem('theme-mode');
    $('#btnChangeTheme').html('Dark Theme: Off');
}
```

The code above works how it's intented but the issue I'm facing is when a user picks the dark theme they still see the light theme for a split second on page load. Does anyone know how I could go around that issue or if I should try something different?

Comment: can you create a plunk for the same ??Its hard to note what exactly is the problem from the code you posted ....

Comment: The problem might be because `theme-dark` might not added to the page to begin with. In addition to storing the theme details on the client, you could save it on the server, and render the page with the correct theme. Or, show a loading screen until your JS has read the the theme and applied it to the page.

Comment: @NisargShah Instead of saving it to the server or showing a loading screen do you think adding that piece of code in the <head> tag could work?

Comment: It *might* work if you add it right after the `body` tag starts. But it is a bad practice to add `script` tags before the DOM as it will slow down the page load. You might want to try and test it on slower network to see how it works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using a class to change the theme, you can use a completely different css.

On the server hold 2 css files: dark.css, light.css.

In index.html  don't refer any of them. Add a script tag in the header that adds a link to the page with the correct css, something like:

```
var link = document.createElement('link');
    link.rel = 'stylesheet';
    link.href = 'css/dark.css';
    document.head.appendChild(link);
```

And the browser will load the css

Comment: The js is in the top of the page, the page won't render until it runs (which is very fast) and then it will load the correct css, so no light/dark theme switch, just loading the correct theme

Comment: Yup, I got it! :) It might still slow down the page a little. I tend to prefer server side code for such things...

Answer (score 1):

To avoid FOUC (Flash of unstyled content) it is better to add an inline script to the `<head>`. But there is a chance that a slow network connection might break our code. Because while doing `$('body')`, `<body>` may not yet exist in the DOM.

I think the best solution would be adding the `theme-dark` class to `<html>`, so there won't be any chance of selecting a non-existing element. In order to deal with button's text we can use some tricks with HTML and CSS.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    var currentTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme-mode');

    if (currentTheme !== null && currentTheme === 'theme-dark') {
      $('html').addClass('theme-dark');
    } else {
      $('html').removeClass('theme-dark');
      localStorage.removeItem('theme-mode');
    }
  </script>

  <style>
    html #btnChangeTheme span.light {
      display: inline;
    }
    html #btnChangeTheme span.dark {
      display: none;
    }

    html.theme-dark #btnChangeTheme span.light {
      display: none;
    }
    html.theme-dark #btnChangeTheme span.dark {
      display: inline;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="btnChangeTheme">
    <span class="dark">
      Dark Theme: On
    </span>
    <span class="light">
      Dark Theme: Off
    </span>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```